# Dont know how to build a method, C# WFA

Tags: c#, .net

While working on a project for school, I have encountered an issue with getting my method to work.

Below is what I need to create:

```
if (operator1 == "+")
{
    //run method "calculate"
}

else if (operator1 == "-")
{
    //run method "calculate"
}
```

Instead of this:

```
if (operator1 == "+")
{
    decimal result = operand1 + operand2;
    txtResult.Text = result.ToString();
}

else if (operator1 == "-")
{
    decimal result = operand1 - operand2;
    txtResult.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

I should have the following:

```
private static Boolean Calculate(this string logic, int operand1, int operand2)
{
    switch (logic)
    {
        case "-": return operand1 - operand2;
        case "+": return operand1 + operand2;
        case "/": return operand1 / operand2;
        case "*": return operand1 * operand2;
        default: throw new Exception("invalid logic");
    }
}
```

This is the concept I tried but was unsuccessful, any suggestions?

For reference, these are the requirements for my project:

> Code a private method named Calculate that performs the requested operation and returns a decimal value. You will need two decimal variables for each operand and a string variable for the operator (to be performed on the 2 values).

Comment: First, I don't think you want the `this` keyword in the function ([extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)). Second, the function should return a `decimal`.

Comment: The function should actually return a `decimal`, as defined by the requirements. The operands should also be defined as `decimal`.

Comment: " unsuccessful" means what. What actually goes wrong

Comment: @MarkusWurst Do not vandalize your questions that way. This behavior is unacceptable, especially not against the answerers who took efforts into answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return a `Boolean` return type. Return a `decimal` instead.

```
private static decimal Calculate(string logic, decimal operand1, decimal operand2)
    {
        switch (logic)
        {
             case "-": 
                return operand1 - operand2;
            case "+": 
                return operand1 + operand2;
            case "/": 
                return operand1 / operand2;
            case "*": 
                return operand1 * operand2;
            default: 
                throw new Exception("invalid logic");
        }
    }
```

This should return the required output as it's `return type` is `decimal`

Comment: That worked, also learned something new today! thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! If you're confused on return types: [Micosoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values) has good documentation on it!

Comment: @MarkusWurst @Symon the operands should be `decimal` as well, as per the requirements.

Comment: @JonathonChase, you'd be right. Slipped past me! Edited the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

Your input and return type's are wrong, try this:

```
private static decimal Calculate(this string logic, decimal operand1, decimal operand2)
{
    switch (logic)
    {
        case "-": return operand1 - operand2;
        case "+": return operand1 + operand2;
        case "/": return operand1 / operand2;
        case "*": return operand1 * operand2;
        default: throw new Exception("invalid logic");
    }
}
```

Also note that you are using an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) which can only be used in a static class.  To change this to a regular method remove the `this` from the method signature.

Comment: i suspect the extensionness is a mistake, seems waay too advanced a concept for this level of question

Answer (score 0):

You defined `Calculate` to return a `Boolean` and are returning a result of type `int`. You need to change the return type to `int`. However, if you are supposed to take two `decimal`s and return a `decimal`, then you should change the return type and operand types to `decimal`.

Answer (score -2):

You've gotten some pretty good answers, I'll just consolidate them here with some error handling which should also be included.

```
    private static decimal Calculate(string logic, decimal operand1, int operand2)
    {
        if (null == logic)
            throw new ArgumentException("logic cannot be null");

        switch (logic)
        {
            case "-":
                return operand1 - operand2;
            case "+":
                return operand1 + operand2;
            case "/":
                return operand1 / operand2;
            case "*":
                return operand1 * operand2;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("logic contains an unknown operator");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you'd like to suggest an addition to another answer, you can leave a comment. It does not need to go in it's own answer.